# Call to map-function doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: clojure

I have the following code:

```
(defn remove-folder [file]
   (do
      (println "Called with file " (.getName file))
      (if (.isDirectory file) 
          (do
           (println (.getName file) " is directory")
           (def children (.listFiles file))
           (println "Number of children " (count children))
           (map remove-folder children)
           (delete-file file)))
          (do
           (println (.getName file) " is file")
           (delete-file file)
          )))
```

My problem is that the line (map remove-folder children) doesn't seem to work. In my output I expect to travel down though the folderstructure but it seems to stay in the first level.

I'll guess I have made some stupid misstake but I spent a few hours on it now and doesn't seem to get closer a solution.

Comment: [`def`](http://clojure.org/special_forms#def) creates a global variable in the current namespace. For local bindings you should use [`let`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/let) instead.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny The original version did the call to .listFiles in the same line as the map. The problem is that the call to map doesn't seem to make any recursive-calls to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ponzao said, `map` is lazy.

But anyway I don't think it's a good idea to use `map` just to get side effects and "drop" the result. Personally I would use `doseq` instead, because it gives a hint that I'm expecting side effects.

```
(defn remove-folder [file]
   (do
      (println "Called with file " (.getName file))
      (if (.isDirectory file) 
          (do
           (println (.getName file) " is directory")
           (def children (.listFiles file))
           (println "Number of children " (count children))
           (doseq [c children]
             (remove-folder c))
           (delete-file file)))
          (do
           (println (.getName file) " is file")
           (delete-file file)
          )))
```

Answer (score 3):

`map` is lazy, wrap it in a `doall` to force evaluation, like this: `(doall (map remove-folder children))`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you inline **children** and get rid of **def**? It doesn't seem that you want to create a global binding in your current namespace. You are unintentionally introducing a side effect.

The function name **remove-folder** does not tell us what the function is supposed to do. The argument name **file** does not describe what kind of argument can be expected. But I understand that it's kind of exploratory code.

Cheers -